# Combining a bootstrap sticky footer with full-height content DIVs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to combine [bootstrap sticky footer](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) with [full-height content DIVs](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-set-a-div-height-to-100-percent-using-css.php). It appears that this question has been answered on the [CSS Tricks site](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/making-100-content-height-with-a-sticky-footer/) but the solution proposed by jurotek appears to have been deleted.

I have searched high and low but cannot find a solution. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Can you post your code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

here you go http://jsfiddle.net/mse22vsk/

```
.page-wrap { height: 100%; }
```

becouse "min-height" and "height" not the same

Comment: Yep! That did it. So simple! Thanks.

Comment: Actually I have discovered that this doesn't actually work. Reposting.

Comment: maybe you post you code on jsfiddle and add link on it?