# CSS: Sticky footer with full-height content DIVs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to combine [bootstrap sticky footer](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) with [full-height content DIVs](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-set-a-div-height-to-100-percent-using-css.php). It appears that this question has been answered on the [CSS Tricks site](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/making-100-content-height-with-a-sticky-footer/) but the solution proposed by jurotek appears to have been deleted.

I previously [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582735/combining-a-bootstrap-sticky-footer-with-full-height-content-divs) and I thought there was a solution provided but it turns out on closer inspection that it doesn't work.

The problem is that full-sized DIVs require a height:100% on all ancestors, but the sticky footer means you can't have this attribute on the HTML element. Thus a conflict.

I am going to investigate using a calc() in the CSS using the height of the viewport, see if that works.

I would really appreciate it if you could help. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Do you know how height your footer will be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the footer to scroll together with the page content, you can use flex divs:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
}

#container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height:100%;
}

#A {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}

#B {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#C {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
<div id=A style="background-color:gold;">header</div>

<div id=B style="background-color:tomato;">
text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>text<br>
</div>

<div id=C style="background-color:gold;">footer</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your excellent skills led me to the solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your div extra content to scroll, you can do it like this:

```css
body {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0px;
}

#content {
height: calc(100% - 30px);
background: gold; 
overflow-y: auto;
}

#footer {
height:30px;
background: tomato;  
}
```

```html
<div id=content>
content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>
</div>
<div id=footer>footer text.</div>
```

Comment: That's great, it's almost perfect, but I don't want the footer to 'stick' to the bottom like that. It needs to scroll with the rest of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the new CSS3 units of Viewport Height and Viewport Width?

Often times when I am using Dynamic content, that is... Dynamic by height, I run across these kinds of errors. I might suggest playing around with `height: 100vh;` or `width: 100vw;`and see if it helps.

I don't see your current code (only code from your old post in SO) so I can't provide a Heuristic or a better solution.

Comment: Yes I have been playing around with the vw units, as well as calc(), but it's not entirely working. Still ongoing.... ;)