# Respond to resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a sticky footer that needs to re-position when the site content grows. Currently when my textarea grows to a certain point, it simply underflows the footer, and that footer is staying as it is.

What is the best way to respond to an element resizing in height? I have seen some stuff using animation frames and such. But all that I want to do is re-calculate the position of my footer each time a resize event is fired.

Comment: [**I did make 2 answers to a sticky footer question yesterday**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627806/css-sticky-footer-with-full-height-content-divs) maybe they can be usefull for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ryan Fait's [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

main {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    /* This line and the next line are not necessary unless you need IE6 support */
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px;
    /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

footer,
.push {
    height: 155px;
    /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

footer {
    height;
    155px;
    background: gray;
}

textarea {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <div class="push"></div>
</main>
<footer>

</footer>
```